# Checking form inputs and changing the text of the submit button on success?

Tags: javascript, forms, button, text

I have a form with a Name, Email, and Text input as well as a Submit button. Clicking Submit checks the fields to make sure there's text in them. If there's text in the fields, clicking submit should submit the form info and change the text of the button to "Sent!"

For whatever reason I can't figure out how to get the button text to change.

```html
    <div class="form-container">
        <form action="/" class="form">
            <div class="inner-form">
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name-field" required>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email-field" required>
                <textarea name="message" id="message-field" cols="30" rows="10"
                    placeholder="Let's hear your idea.." required></textarea>
                <button class="form-button" type="submit" href="/">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

```js
const nameField = document.querySelector("#name-field").value;
const emailField = document.querySelector("#email-field").value;
const textField = document.querySelector("#message-field").value;
const form = document.querySelector(".form");
const formButton = document.querySelector(".form-button");

form.addEventListener("click", validateField);

function validateField(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  if (nameField === "") {
    $('#name-field').attr('placeholder', 'Please enter your name.');
    $('#name-field').addClass('needText');
  }
  
  if (emailField === "") {
    $('#email-field').attr('placeholder', 'Please enter your email.');
    $('#email-field').addClass('needText');
  }
  
  if (textField === "") {
    $('#message-field').attr('placeholder', 'Please enter your message.');
    $('#message-field').addClass('needText');
  } else {
    formButton.innerText = "Sent!";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some HTML in your demo. Also, you should use a form submit event handler, not click. There's more than one way to submit a form.

Comment: Note that updating placeholder text may not be considered an accessible strategy. If visually impaired users aren't made aware of the change it's not helpful.

Comment: Your code for changing the text of the button is in an `else` after `if (textField === "")`. Why are you only updating that if the textField is filled in?

Comment: You're correct. I misread you. Good code formatting goes a long way. Ninety9Balloons, you can see that the formatting I applied with the editor's Tidy button, plus whitespace between if statements, makes your logic much more clear.

Comment: @isherwood got to the edit before me, but yes .. The else is on `textField` only

Comment: Ignoring several other issues I see with your logic, I'll ask whether there's more than one element on your page with a class of `form-button`. Because `document.querySelector(".form-button")` is going to return the first one it finds, and that's not necessarily the one whose text you're trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the validation logic from the logic to show feedback to the user. They'll be handled separately.

You can do this by rechecking all values together with OR operators, or just use a variable to track it.

```js
const nameField = document.querySelector("#name-field").value;
const emailField = document.querySelector("#email-field").value;
const textField = document.querySelector("#message-field").value;
const form = document.querySelector(".form");
const formButton = document.querySelector(".form-button");
let emptyFieldFound = false;

form.addEventListener("click", validateField);

function validateField(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  if (nameField === "") {
    emptyFieldFound = true;
    $('#name-field').attr('placeholder', 'Please enter your name.');
    $('#name-field').addClass('needText');
  }
  
  if (emailField === "") {
    emptyFieldFound = true;
    $('#email-field').attr('placeholder', 'Please enter your email.');
    $('#email-field').addClass('needText');
  }
  
  if (textField === "") {
    emptyFieldFound = true;
    $('#message-field').attr('placeholder', 'Please enter your message.');
    $('#message-field').addClass('needText');
  }
  
  if (!emptyFieldFound) {
    formButton.innerText = "Sent!";
  }
}
```

That said, I'd encourage you to look into modern [HTML5 form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation). You can automate some of the things you're doing here with the `required` input attribute and form validity properties.

Answer (score 0):

`const nameField = document.querySelector("#name-field").value;`
Your Selection are selected only value of this DOM element, You can try this way

```
$(".form").submit(validateField());

function validateField(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if ($("#name-field").val() === "") {
    $("#name-field").attr("placeholder", "Please enter your name.");
    $("#name-field").addClass("needText");
  }

  if ($("#email-field").val() === "") {
    $("#email-field").attr("placeholder", "Please enter your email.");
    $("#email-field").addClass("needText");
  }

  if ($("#message-field").val() === "") {
    $("#message-field").attr("placeholder", "Please enter your message.");
    $("#message-field").addClass("needText");
  } else {
    $("#message-field").html("Sent!");
  }
}
```